# how to verify entire web site with Selenium ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'd like to verify that all pages of a website, meet the following conditions:

```
assertElementPresent --> div.box
assertElementPresent --> #footer
assertElementNotPresent --> msg-error
```

In other words, It has a header, a footer, and does not have any error message.

Well, I can do this using Selenium ID, but adding these commands link by link, or command by command. 
What I'm  wondering, if there's any way to configure these 3 commands for the entire web site, instead of adding one by one per each link.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Without knowing any other details, its hard to give you any advice...

Comment: Just wondering if I can save my time, just applying those rules one time only.

Comment: But still depends on how the page looks like, how your tests like ... It can be helpful, it can be not. My advice is: Try it and see what happens...\

Comment: I just need to check these 3 verifications, but I need to know if there's a way to configure them only once. So....try what? !?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The commands would most likely need to be put into your script after every navigation.

Best thing I could suggest would be that when you're recording your script put a 'wait for title' command in after every link navigation as you're recording it. That way you should be able to open the script itself in a text editor and just do a find and replace all on the wait for title. So for example

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=link</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForTitle</td>
    <td>page title</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Then find and replace:

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForTitle</td>
```

with

```
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>div.box</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>#footer</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>msg-error</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForTitle</td>
```